# Why does LinkedIn API not give unique skill IDs?

Tags: api, linkedin-api

The [Skills](http://developer.linkedin.com/documents/profile-fields#skills) part of "Profile Fields" page on LinkedIn API says for `id` field:

```
A unique identifier for a single skill in the list of skills
```

When I try to get the `id` of the skills a user has, it returns me a bunch of numbers generally starting from 1 and increasing one by one or by minor gaps. So I understand that the ids it returns are the order of that user's own skill list, not the unique ids LinkedIn should have on its database. Why doesn't it return the unique skill ids while providing unique user, school, company ids?

**An example from my skill list:**

```
 [8] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [id] => 17
                            [skill] => stdClass Object
                                (
                                    [name] => JavaScript
                                )

                        )
```

**An example from my friend's skill list:**

```
 [3] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [id] => 4
                            [skill] => stdClass Object
                                (
                                    [name] => JavaScript
                                )

                        )
```

**The request URL I'm using is as below:**

```
http://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~:(skills:(id,skill:(name)))?format=json
```

Comment: No, still waiting for an answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, from what I see in the documents, there are two types of entities: global and local (per-user, per-company, etc.)
Speaking of profile fields, its clearly seen in documentation:

**Local entities:**

1. Positions
2. Skills
3. Publications

etc.. In docuemntation, the ids for these entities are referred to as: 
`a unique identifier for this member's position`, `A unique identifier for a single skill in the list of skills`. But the IDs are still per user - i.e. unique in the list only and not globally.

**Global entities:**

1. User himself
2. Company

In description, the following is written:
`the ID for the company (useful with facets or the Company API)`

At least this is how I interpret this document, whether or not it's authoritative enough for you is up to you :)

Comment: This seems correct by my reading as well. They don't track the skills uniquely across users in the API.